# GHUB two functions in one lua

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech-gaming-software

guys im very newbee in lua scriptings, and i hate ghub i have to say, so in short.. i want this two luas in one (1st is very simple recoil script and the 2nd is (should have been) a simple bind, like if i click mouse1 script click mouse3 and release it. But since on one application ghub cannot load two luas at the same time - i need help, because if i try connect them, i i get delay from 1st function and etc

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
repeat
if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
repeat
MoveMouseRelative(0,2)
Sleep(11.0)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
end
end
```

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")then ------ (I want to be able switch this func on\off)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
        repeat
            PressKey("lalt")   ------- (or mouse3 in my case)
            Sleep(20)
            ReleaseKey("lalt") ------- (or mouse3 in my case)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
end
```

Comment: Should `mouse3` be pressed on LMB press while in recoil?  Or the two scripts should never intersect their behavior?

Comment: mouse3 is for "tag enemies", but i wanted that to be by pressing mouse1, so for example if i start shoot (holding mouse3 for ADS) on mouse1 script will press mouse3 once, but i think yes, mouse3 should be pressed ONCE the mouse1 is pressed,  it doesn't matter if i holding mouse3 or not, i just wanted the simple "re-bind from m3 to m1) but not lose functionality.

as i know btw - mouse3 in ghub lua is right mouse button, not middle, so again: (1)-LMB (2)-MMB (3)-RMB, i did a mistake in second lua in notes (----mouse3 = middle mb)

Comment: So, "tag enemies" and "ADS" are on the same button?  How is that possible?

Comment: `mouse3` sometimes means RMB, sometimes MMB.  So, when you say `mouse3` I don't understand which button you refer to.

Comment: sorry, once again, I just need these 2 different functions to be in one lua script, i dont know, i think they should intersect their behavior, because scenario for the first one (recoil) is: if i hold RMB and then if i hold LMB - recoil is working. But at the same time when i start to hold LMB for recoil - i click it once obviously, so the second function should perform its action (just click MMB once, and repeat that, if i will press it once more )

Answer (score 0):

The second script will work not continuously, unlike in the original script.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
        PressMouseButton(2)  -- MMB
        Sleep(20)
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)  -- MMB
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then  -- RMB
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0,2)
                Sleep(11)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)  -- LMB
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! But somehow MMB in game doesn't work at all, cant understand why, (tested in two games) if i just click LMB - MMB doesn't work. But i just change it from 

PressMouseButton(2)  -- MMB to  PressKey('lalt') and bind ping on ALT ingame and it works perfectly! Thanks for help again